# JavaFX Application keeps running even if i have an error in my main class static initializer

Tags: java, javafx-8

Keeps running:

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    static {
        throwAnException();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static void throwAnException() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

Stops:

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throwAnException();
        launch(args);
    }

    private static void throwAnException() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

Why?

In the first case the program keeps running, even with the exception.
In the second case the program stops before calling the javafx thread.
The static initializer should run before the main method, right?
My english is vary bad so i didn't write much.
I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a cheap answer

It keeps running because there are 4(3) other Threads running ..

when you exit/close/shutdown your application through `stop()` you kill it the right way, also i think, the `main Thread` is triggered after the `stop()` method so if you have an exception there, it pretty much happens after the show, if you throw the exception in the `init()` method the app shutdowns for real - the `init()` method starts two additional threads..

replace this and see

```
static {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("There are "+ Thread.activeCount()+" still running");
            }
        }
    }).start();
    throwAnException();
}
```